# Why do I get a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I thought using the

```
if (data[i] != null)
```

I would avoid the exception, but I still get it.
This is my code.

```
public Object get(String key)
{
    int i = hashCode(key);
    while (i != capacity)
    {
        if (data[i] != null)
        {
            if (key.equals(data[i].key()))
                return data[i].element();
            else
                i++;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }                   
    return null;
}
```

data[i] is an empty array, all are null.

When i execute the method `.get()` I get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You should be able to see the exact line that causes the NPE from the stacktrace. Which line is it ?

Comment: What do you see when you catch this exception in your debugger?

Comment: problem solved. I didnt realize In my main i requested 'get().toString()' 'get().' returns an Object but I think you cant call toString of null-object thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked printstack trace at what line you getting the nullpointer exception?

I think you should also check if `data` array itself is null or not.

```
//EDIT: Taking the liberty to add code
if(data!=null && data[i]!=null)
{

}
```

Comment: I made a separate method to return 'data[i]'. data[i] for example data[0] returns null. If you make an array alls cells are null, am I right? This method doesn't return Exception, but the get method does.

Comment: NEVERMIND.I solved the bug. The error was in my main. I tried to call the toString method of the null Object that was returned.